# Can't get a css stylesheet in flask to apply (issue with url_for())

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm following some basic tutorials to get a css stylesheet to apply to an html file using flask. I am doing exactly what the tutorials have shown, but for some reason the stylesheet does not apply to the html.

Here is the main.css file:

```
body {
    margin: 50px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Here is the base.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/main.css')}}">
    <title>Document</title>
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my index.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Image Upload</h1>
<form id="upload form" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the app.py file if it is needed:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route("/")
def index():
    """Landing page. Has an image upload button."""
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    """Page displayed after an image is uploaded. Currently it just displays the image and has a button to go back to the landing page."""
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static/images/')
    print(target)

    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    for file in request.files.getlist("file"):
        print(file)
        filename = file.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print(destination)
        file.save(destination)
    return render_template("uploaded.html", image_name=filename)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Add some spaces between curly braces, e.g. `href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">` and see if that works. If it doesn't, then make sure that your static root is actually correct, e.g. if your static is set to `/home/something` and your file is based in `css/main.css`, the actual path should be `/home/something/css/main.css`

Answer (score 0):

Solved on my own! Turns out I'm just a little dumb. It was just a caching issue, the code above worked fine when I ctrl-shift-r'd.